# schema access for postgres database is fine from toad, but get a schema permission denied from an application

Tags: postgresql

I have created a user role cadmin. When logged in as cadmin, I create a schema and create tables in the schema. This is with postgress 9.3

I am able to access the schema and query the tables perfectly fine from a tool like TOAD. However, from an application connected to the database, i always get an error that "permission is denied to the schema'. In the same application, I use jooq and that using the same role and the schema is able to find all the tables and create the classes. Just that when I do a 'Select' i get the error.

"nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for schema core_engine"

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting with the same user every time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant the permission for schema. So, you could try using following query from tool like TOAD and then run the application

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_name TO postgres_user_name;
```